# openui5 dom attach in treetable

Tags: sapui5

Attaching a dom object to openui5 treetable.
**But table is coming blank.**

```
let domModel = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<nodata>sample data</nodata>", "text/xml");
domModel = {
  data : {
    childNodes : domModel.childNodes
  }
};
var oJsonModel = new JSONModel({domModel});
this.getView().setModel(oJsonModel);
```

In xml treetable is attaching like bellow

```
<TreeTable rows="{path:'/data', parameters: {arrayNames:['childNodes']}}">
```

In xml treetable column is like bellow.

```
<Column>
  <template>
    <m:Text text="{nodeName}" wrapping="false" />
  </template>
</Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the aggregation binding, the data needs to be an array. Try the binding like this:

path: ‘/data/childNodes’ ...

PS: I’m assuming childNodes is an array.